# ASP.NET Identity - How to allow access to ONLY the logged in User?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have a **StudentController** page which I want to display only the information of the User who is currently logged in. Like right now when a student logs in to his account, he is able to see the list of all the students in the University.

[image: Students page]

I want to restrict the view to only his account. I am trying to work with the Index method in the Controller, but I am experiencing issues with the PagedList View when I try to get students by `User.Identity.GetUserId() select s;` instead of `studentRepository.GetStudents()`.

```
// GET: /Student/

        public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
        {
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
            ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

            if (searchString != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }
            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

            //var students = from s in User.Identity.GetUserId() select s;

            var students = from s in studentRepository.GetStudents()
                           select s;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                students = students.Where(s => s.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                       || s.FirstMidName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
            }
            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "name_desc":
                    students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.LastName);
                    break;
                case "Date":
                    students = students.OrderBy(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
                    break;
                case "date_desc":
                    students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
                    break;
                default:  // Name ascending 
                    students = students.OrderBy(s => s.LastName);
                    break;
            }

            int pageSize = 3;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(students.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }

        //
        // GET: /Student/Details/5

        public ViewResult Details(int id)
        {
            Student student = studentRepository.GetStudentByID(id);
            return View(student);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a where clause in your linq query there to display only that student's information :

```
var loggedInStudentId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

from s in studentRepository.GetStudents()
where s.StudentId == loggedInStudentId 
select s
```

### UPDATE:

you can check if user is not admin then show only his own record like:

```
var students = from s in studentRepository.GetStudents()
               select s;


 if(!User.IsInRole("Admin"))
 {
     var loggedInStudentId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
     students = students.Where(x=>x.StudentId = loggedInStudentId);
 }
```

Comment: It works for when I log in as a Student. But when I log in as an Admin, it is supposed to show all the Students, but it doesn't?

Comment: you have to check if user is not admin then apply the filter

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
        var students = from s in studentRepository.GetStudents()
                       where s.Id = User.Identity.GetUserId()
                       select s;
```

you'll have to use whatever identity column you're using on student that would match up with GetUserId(), I put s.Id in here for example